# Using Stuff to roll up data from multiple rows AND concatenate columns

Tags: sql, string-aggregation

I've found similar questions on the site, but I'm still struggling with this. I have a table with information like the below:

```
AcctNo   ChargeOrder    ChargeCode
 ABC         1           Charge1
 ABC         2           Charge2
 ABC         3           Charge3
```

I'm trying to use the XML Path/STUFF functions to return the data like so:

```
AcctNo  Order/Code
ABC     1:Charge1 - 2:Charge2 - 3:Charge3
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to concatenate my chargeorder and chargecode AND STUFF them into a single field.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can use `string_agg()` -- in the more recent versions:

```
select acctno,
       string_agg(concat(ChargeOrder, ':', ChargeCode), ' - ')
from t
group by acctno;
```

In older versions, this would be phrased as:

```
select a.acctno,
       stuff( (select concat(' - ', ChargeOrder, ':', ChargeCode)
               from t t2
               where t2.acctno = a.acctno
               for xml path ('')
              ), 1, 3, ''
            )
from (select distinct acctno from t) a
```

Comment: thank you. Unfortunately, I can't use the recent version (which looks FAR easier!). In the second version you provided, you are referencing 2 tables, t and t2...do I need this even though my data is all in the same table

Comment: @user2938667 . . . It is only referencing one table.  `t2` and `a` are table aliases.